# How to download files from google drive using google drive api?

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I am able to download files but the problem is downloaded  file  corrupted. And I have tried a lot of examples all results the same. Any idea what went wrong here?

```
 drive.files
            .get({ fileId: '1X5Ygf8WuZXqsjtRT0IIzD9_N2idzpylMNX2P93wB5a4', alt: 'media' }, { responseType: 'stream' })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res, 33);

                const filePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), uuid.v4());
                console.log(`writing to ${filePath}`);
                const dest = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
                let progress = 0;

                res.data
                    .on('end', () => {
                        console.log('Done downloading file.');
                        cb(filePath);
                    })
                    .on('error', err => {
                        console.error('Error downloading file.');
                        reject(err);
                    })
                    .on('data', d => {
                        progress += d.length;
                        if (process.stdout.isTTY) {
                            process.stdout.clearLine();
                            process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
                            process.stdout.write(`Downloaded ${progress} bytes`);
                        }
                    })
                    .pipe(dest);

            });
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. If you can see the error message, please show it. 2. From the length of your file ID, I thought that you might be trying to download a Google Docs file (Spreadsheet, Document and Slides). If my understanding is correct, In this case, please use the export method of Drive API instead of the get method. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads) Also, you can see the sample script for googleapis with Node.js at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60027518/7108653). How about this? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: I didn't get any error and also I am trying to download image file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: @Tanaike I have solved the issue by using wecontentlink . Thank you for interest shown

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will help users who have the same issue.